# Can I say that "excludes" is an antonym of "includes"?

Tags: antonyms

Can I say that the word "**excludes**" is the antonym of "**includes**"?

Actually for me it look like as *one* origin with two different *prefixes* only: **EX**-clude and **IN**-clude. 
But I didn't find it as an antonym and that's why I suspect maybe it is not considered so. Look carefully in the list of the antonyms made by google - below:

[image]

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exclude

Comment: Yes, _in-_ and _ex-_ (from the Latin for _in_ and _out,_ roughly) are frequently used in English words with their roots in Latin or the Romance languages (_inhale/exhale, interior/exterior, internal/external,_ e.g.) in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in- and ex- (from the Latin for in and out, roughly) are frequently used in English words with their roots in Latin or the Romance languages (inhale/exhale, interior/exterior, internal/external, e.g.) in this way. –